# Generating reports with dynamic field filters in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am displaying a list of model fields and related fields to the user. Users can set the filter on one or multiple fields. I need to return results according to those filters.

Here is my Employee Model

```
    employeeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    joiningDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    department = models.IntegerField()
    designation = models.IntegerField()
    qualification = models.CharField()
    highestDegree = models.CharField()    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fatherName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    motherName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GenderTypes.choices(), null=True, blank=True)
    religion = models.IntegerField(choices=ReligionChoices.choices())
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CategoryChoices.choices())
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Other than these model fields, Users can apply a filter on some connected fields as well like salary which is stored in another table with employeeID as a foreign key. Filters can be particular values as well as range, as in the case of salary (10000 - 20000).

I know Django does not provide such a facility and I need to write custom logic. I just needed to confirm that should I write hard-coded logic for every field or there is a way where I can find if a particular field belongs to that model or not. In case it does not, is there a way where I can derive the relation of that particular field from the model? These two things combined should give us enough to implement this.

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: Django doesn't have this functionality. If I have a choice, I would write some logic to wrap the input from client and forward to Django ORM

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I updated my question to be more particular. Can you have look?

Comment: Why not use the standard Django filter https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/?

Comment: @Ken4scholars That's exactly what I was looking for. It also gave me an idea of how to implement this if I don't want to use the package. I would have accepted this as answer if you had posted an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Django-Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is the standard package used for filtering in Django applications.